# stream / progressive download a video file while it's being rendered

Tags: video, streaming, render, mp4

I'm trying to render a video file (with after effects), preferably H.264, and while rendering, start streaming the file that's created. that way the client doesn't have to wait for the whole video to be rendered. in the case of mp4, Adobe AE creates a temp m4v file that doesn't include the moov atom (which is only added to the final mp4 file) thus preventing it's playback on the client's browser. is there another way or other file formats (other than flv!) that can be streamed while being created ?

Comment: Isaac did you got a solution for this?

Comment: It was a long time ago, but I think we went to another solution - cutting the video to small chunks and rendering them simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

What you have observed is an expected behavior in the case of any .mp4 muxer. This is because .mp4 maintains a heavy metadata which makes it efficient while playback.

One other format you can try is MPEG2 TS (ISO 13818 - Part 1) which is basically transport stream but seems suitable for the use case you have mentioned.